# Printing answer when using map. Python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to create code in order to take sequence A and B and multiply them together in order to get a new list.

e.g. if the two inputs were:
1,5,7
3,5,8

The new list would be:
3,25,56.

The current code I have is as follows.

```
print ("INPUT:")
num_sequence_A = input( "enter sequence A: " ) 
num_sequence_B = input( "enter sequence B: " )
```

`#calculation in order to calculate for new list.
calc = map(lambda x,y:x*y,num_sequence_A,num_sequence_B)`

I cannot however find a way to print the calculation.
I have tried :

```
calc = map(print, lambda x,y:x*y,num_sequence_A,num_sequence_B)
```

and

```
list(map(print, calc))
```

with no success.

Comment: `print(*calc, sep='\n')`.

Comment: I like ^ better than the answers

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert you inputs to arrays of int.

```
num_sequence_A = input("enter sequence A: ")
num_sequence_B = input("enter sequence B: ")

num_sequence_A = [int(i) for i in num_sequence_A.split(',')]
num_sequence_B = [int(i) for i in num_sequence_B.split(',')]
```

Then, calculate the result:

```
calc = map(lambda x, y: x * y, num_sequence_A, num_sequence_B)
```

Finally, print the output:

```
print(','.join([str(i) for i in calc]))
```

Additionally, you can use `re`:

```
import re

num_sequence_A = input("enter sequence A: ")  # 3.4 5.6 7.8
num_sequence_B = input("enter sequence B: ")  # 4.5 7 6

num_sequence_A = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)', num_sequence_A)
num_sequence_B = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)', num_sequence_B)

num_sequence_A = [float(i[0]) if len(i[0]) != 0 else float(i[1]) for i in num_sequence_A]
num_sequence_B = [float(i[0]) if len(i[0]) != 0 else float(i[1]) for i in num_sequence_B]

calc = map(lambda x, y: x * y, num_sequence_A, num_sequence_B)

print(','.join(['%.2f' % i for i in calc]))
```

Comment: @danh would it be possible to format this so the result is [0,1,4,9,16]?

Comment: use `calc = list(map(lambda x, y: x * y, num_sequence_A, num_sequence_B))`

Comment: @StefanPochmann: because I think he wants to use only `map` function

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution with:
`num_sequence_A = input( "enter sequence A: ")`
in which i receive an error. It only works when I change the input sequence to:
`num_sequence_A = range(5 )`

Comment: @pete: You receive an error because this function `lambda x, y: x * y`. You **can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`, `filter` or list comprehensions to create new iterables and never for side-effects like printing. To print the items in `calc` you can just use a for loop.

```
calc = map(lambda x, y: x*y, num_sequence_A, num_sequence_B)

for num in calc:
    print(num)
```

Comment: Or simply: for x, y in zip(A, B): print(x * y)